# Service Fabric port binding with containers

Tags: azure, docker, azure-service-fabric

So there is an ability in Docker to `EXPOSE` port internally to communicate between services and listening to the same port. Like in this fragment of Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:$DotnetVersion-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
# Container healthcheck
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=30s --retries=3 \
    CMD curl --silent --fail http://localhost/api/status/check || exit 1

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet",  "Assembly.dll"]
```

I can run a bunch of the same image instances and if they're in the same network - they can communicate with each other through an 80th port. I found an article [here about networking](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-networking-modes.md) but it seems that we need to create a separate network interface for each service instance and this approach has limitations in Azure (each VM size tier has limited amount of network connections). Also, I know there is an option to use different ports, but I want to keep configuration minimal and this is the last resort. So how to achieve the same behavior like in docker engine in Service Fabric?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @LoekD accidentally wiped out. Updated.

Comment: Can you explain more about what the problem is that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @LoekD Problem is in default Service Fabric approach in port allocation, that port is exposed directly on VM network interface, thus I can't deploy more than one service that listens 80th port and I'm searching for some workaround. Because I want to deploy multiple services that listen to 80th port (via sub-networks, etc).

Comment: Oh, I see. Are you sure you cannot use a /the reverse proxy to solve your problem using dynamic ports? So connect a dynamic host port to port 80 inside a container and rely on the reverse proxy to route traffic. e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers#configure-communication

Comment: @LoekD will look in this way, thanks. But there is no reverse proxy in Linux cluster ATM.

Comment: have a look at traefik, which does a nicer job (imo) than the built-in rp. https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric